Kotlin Multiplatform - wasm streaming compile failed: TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': Incorrect response MIME type
Getting this error when running the web app build using Kotlin Multiplatform in live, but works well on localhost. do we need to do anything with host server?, I am very beginner with this, please help
I published the KMP web app using the jetbrains documentation
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/kotlin-multiplatform-dev/multiplatform-publish-apps.html#web-app
but in hostinger, when i run in live, I get the following error

Update : When I run the same in github pages its working well, but not on hostinger, need any configurations or setup for wasm and hostinger? ps: I'm newbie

Update: Hostinger don't support wasm yet. they said we have to purchase seperate plan for that. Thanks
